# Suggestions for Optimizing code

Tags: java

```
public Object getValue()
{
    ValueItem valueItem = null;
    Object returnValue = null;

    if(this.value instanceof StringValueImpl)
    {
        valueItem = (StringValueImpl) this.value;
    }
    else if(this.value instanceof ListValueImpl)
    {
        valueItem = (ListValueImpl) this.value;
    }
    else if(this.value instanceof MapValueImpl)
    {
        valueItem = (MapValueImpl) this.value;
    }

    if(valueItem!=null)
        returnValue = valueItem.getValue();

    return returnValue;
}
```

`ValueItem` is an `interface` which is implemented by `ListValueImpl`, `MapValueImpl` etc .. I want return value which is an `object`. The code works fine but i was wondering if this can be improved in any way  ?

Comment: public Object getValue() { return this.value; } should work just fine

Comment: What's the point of the `ValueItem` interface?  If its implementations hold unrelated types like strings and lists, I doubt it's an abstraction of any functionality they have in common.  If its purpose is just that you can call `getValue()` on it and receive an `Object`, why not just use `Object` instead of `ValueItem` for your variables?

Comment: Feel bad for whoever (if anyone) has to maintain your code..

Comment: Do you have more implementations of `ValueItem` than `StringValueImpl`, `ListValueImpl` and `MapValueImpl`?

Comment: This looks almost like he is trying to accomplish the same goals as the Joda Beans project, except Joda's `Property` interface is now `ValueItem`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the type of `this.value`? If it is `ValueItem` then you don't need to do any of this and can replace the method with this:

```
public Object getValue()
{
    Object returnValue = null;
    if(this.value!=null)
        returnValue = this.value.getValue();
    return returnValue;
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
public Object getValue()
{
    return this.value!=null ? this.value.getValue() : null;
}
```

If `this.value` is **not** of type `ValueItem` *but* it *has to* contain a `ValueItem`, then you have a design problem at your hand.

Comment: Almost, unless there are more implementations of `ValueItem` than `StringValueImpl`, `ListValueImpl` and `MapValueImpl`.

Comment: @Howard: if there are more implementations, then *not* mentioning them here is probably a bug anyway.

Comment: I agree that such information should be given. Nevertheless it is worth mentioning because it changes functionality if it is the case.

Comment: @Joachim:The shorter version, does it have any performance benefit over the longer?

Comment: @user384706: not really. And **please** believe me when I tell you that you won't find any relevant performance optimizations at **that** level. *Most* of your performance will be lost in design issues and the rest you'll have to hunt for with profilers: **don't try to guess** when it comes to performance. You will be wrong. *Everyone* is wrong when they try to guess where the performance problem is.

Answer (score 1):

My inclination is that your `getValue()` isn't doing anything for you at all.  You're detecting what class it is, casting it to that class, then shoving it into an Object again.  ...so you'll have to do the same kind of detection on the caller's side of `getValue()` anyways!

Personally, I'd do it like this:

```
public boolean isaStringValueImpl() {
    return (this.value instanceof StringValueImpl);
}
public boolean isaListValueImpl() {
    return (this.value instanceof ListValueImpl);
}
public boolean isaMapValueImpl() {
    return (this.value instanceof MapValueImpl);
}

public StringValueImpl getAsaStringValueImpl() {
    return (StringValueImpl)this.value;
}
public ListValueImpl getAsaListValueImpl() {
    return (ListValueImpl)this.value;
}
public MapValueImpl getAsaMapValueImpl() {
    return (MapValueImpl)this.value;
}
```

In addition to the regular getter:

```
public ValueItem getValueItem() {
   return this.value;
}
```

But even with all this, I'd say that you might have a larger design issue that could be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

How about a generics based type safe version.

```
public abstract class ValueItem<T> {

    public abstract T getValue();

    public class StringValueImpl extends ValueItem<String> {
        private String value;

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public class ListValueImpl extends ValueItem<List<?>> {
        private List<?> value;

        public List<?> getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public class MapValueImpl extends ValueItem<Map<?, ?>> {
        private Map<?, ?> value;

        public Map<?, ?> getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```